# Using exclamation marks in bash expansion

Tags: bash

In bash, I build a svn command as a string with username and password options dynamically added. Some users might have an exclamation mark in their password, which might result in the following:

```
svncmd='svn update --username=user --password password\! --non-interactive'
$($svncmd)
```

But this expands my exclamation mark, which is not what I want. What am I missing?

EDIT:

Ah, I think I know what is happening. With this command, I can just run it like $svncmd instead of $($svncmd). What was happening was bash was complaining about bash: At: command not found... when it was trying to run "At revision xxxxx" as a command. Oops.

Comment: Have you seen that history expansion is triggered or are you just afraid this would happen? `echo $(echo foo! bar)` doesn't...

Comment: Remove the backslash, because you use quote, so bash treats everything inside as literal

Comment: @Gnouc Even within double quotes the backslash would be treated literally if a "!" follows.

Comment: I have erroneously attributed this to expansion problems when I was trying to run the command like $($svncmd))... when running $svncmd actually executes the command already and returns "At Revision XXXXX". This is then interpreted by the outer $() and bash complained that it couldn't find the "At" command.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a command in a variable and then executing it as intended is tricky, because of the order in which the shell parses the command line. It parses (and applies and removes) quotes and escapes, then substitutes variables, then does word splitting and wildcard expansion, but doesn't go back and interpret escapes and quotes in the substituted variable values. As a result, if the command stored in a variable has quotes or escapes, they won't have the intended effect. Suppose, for example, that the user's password was 'foo * bar' if you set the command to `svncmd='svn update --username=user --password foo * bar --non-interactive'` and then execute it as `$svncmd`, it'll take 'foo' as the password, then get a list of files in the current directory followed by 'bar' as separate arguments. On the other hand, if you stored the command as `svncmd='svn update --username=user --password "foo * bar" --non-interactive'`, it'd take '"foo' as the password, then the list of files followed by 'bar"'...

The best way to handle this in bash is generally to store the command as an array (where each "word" of the command is an array element), then invoke it as `"${svncmd[@]}"` -- the `[@]` makes it treat each element as a command word, and the double-quotes prevent any additional parsing of the array elements after they're substituted in.  Thus, you'd build the command something like this:

```
svncmd=(svn update --username=user)
if [ $pwdfromvar ]; then
    svncmd+=(--password "$userpw")  # Double-quotes allow variable substitution, prevent parsing of the substituted value
elif [ $defaultpw ]; then
    svncmd+=(--password 'password!')  # Single-quotes prevent the ! from being interpreted
else
    IFS= read -rs -p "Password:"  # Raw read without echo
    echo
    svncmd+=(--password "$REPLY")
fi
svncmd+=(--non-interactive)

"${svncmd[@]}"
```